# How can I allow applications to bind to any address in a subnet assigned to an interface?

Tags: networking, socket, ipv6

I recently got a static IPv6 /56 prefix of my own from Freenet6, and am trying to allow applications to bind arbitrary addresses in the prefix. I modified the tunnel creation script that `gogoc` uses in order to assign both the client address (here we'll call it `2001:5c0:1000::cccc/128`) and the entire subnet I have allocated (here called `2001:5c0:2000:5800::/56`) to `tun` and `tun:1`, respectively. I can bind an application to listen on `2001:5c0::cccc` or `2001:5c0:5800::` just fine, and using IPv6 open port testers indicates that the connection is succeeding.

However, the dilemma lies in that I am unable to bind an address like `2001:5c0:2000:5800:1111:2222:3333:4444`, which is part of the subnet I assigned to `tun:1`, getting `EADDRNOTAVAIL` as an error code. `socat` reads:

```
2014/05/10 12:12:06 socat[16940] E bind(3, {AF=10 [2001:5c0:2000:5800:1111:2222:3333:4444]:9876}, 28): Cannot assign requested address
```

The application I wish to use does not support `IP_FREEBIND` or `IP_TRANSPARENT`.

Is there a kernel setting I can use to implicitly free-bind sockets? Or perhaps a way to intercept socket creation from a given process, and attach socket options to that creation?

`ip addr`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:7d:7b:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9c:b7:0d:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: wlan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:c0:ff:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.8/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global wlan1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2c0:ffff:feff:70d1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: tun: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1280 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet6 2001:5c0:1103:5800::/56 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2001:5c0:1000:b::5225/128 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: I think it's you can't bind *specific* address if it's not assigned to some interface. Could you post what does `ip addr` print out?

Comment: @TNW It's assigned, implicitly, as I understand. I assigned a subnet that contains that address to that interface (as the address itself, not the subnet mask)

Comment: You don't assign prefixes to interfaces, you assign addresses (from the prefix that belongs to that link) to interfaces. Out of curiosity: why do you want 4722366482869645213696 addresses on one interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part of your interface config, namely `inet6 2001:5c0:1103:5800::/56` in `ip addr` listing, means two things:

1. `2001:5c0:1103:5800::` is assigned to your interface - you can `ping6` it to find out it's valid, whereas `2001:5c0:1103:5800::1` won't respond
2. `/56` serves for routing purposes, and means only that if you want to send something to the network with that prefix (`inet6 2001:5c0:1103:5800::/56`), it should go out using the `tun` interface. You can find that out using `ip -6 route`.

For how to do what you want, [you can check out this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/209203/can-i-bind-a-large-block-of-addresses-to-an-interface%22this%22).

Now, why did the binds work? It's because you can use a network address in `bind` call, and it will bind your socket to interface(s) which have access to the given network (specifically binding to 0.0.0.0 binds to all interfaces, rather than to all of the IPs in the Internet).